# Dynamically add QAction to a QToolbar and create classmethods

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, closures, pyqt4

1. I want a QToolBar to be instantiated like:

   ```
   tools = customTools(actions=['action_one', 'action_two', 'action_three'])
   ```
2. and the classmethods to be added programmatically, so there is (corresponding to the signal emitted by each action):

   ```
   tools.action_one()
   tools.action_two()...
   ```
3. These methods shall be available outside of "tools" so they can call methods of other classes like:

   ```
   class customTools(QtGui.QToolBar):
       """represents a custom QToolBar"""
       ...
       def action_one(self):
           some_other_classes.function()
   ```
4. Right now, im stuck here:

   ```
   class customTools(QtGui.QToolBar):
       def __init__(self, actions=[]):
           QtGui.QToolBar.__init__(self, parent=None)

           #actions to toolbar QAction
           for name in actions:
               action = QtGui.QAction(name, self)
               self.addAction(action)
               action.triggered[()].connect(
                   lambda name=name: self.tool_name(name))

       def tool_name(self, name):
           # stuck here...
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This works for now:

inside classmethod:

```
def tool_name(self, f):
    self.function = getattr(self, f)
    self.function()
```

instantiate:

```
def main():
    names = ['action_one', 'action_two']
    tools = customTools([name for name in names])
```

define function:

```
def action_one(self):
    return some_other_classes.function()
```

add as classmethod:

```
setattr(tools, action_one.__name__, MethodType(action_one, tools, type(tools)))
```

(found here: http://dietbuddha.blogspot.com/2012/12/python-metaprogramming-dynamically.html, don't forget the credits, though...)